# Laravel dosen't clear $errors variable when i refresh the page

Tags: php, validation, laravel

when i submit my form and check validation on laravel and laravel returns $errors to my page and i show it by code that is on the bottom , it shows the errors but when i refresh the page this errors remains.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="margin-top-10">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

and also i see this error on my browser

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and here is my validation code

```
$rules = array(
    'first_name'=>'required|alpha|max:255',
    'last_name'=>'required|alpha|max:255',
    'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'username'=>'required|unique:users,name|max:255',
);
$messages = array(
    'first_name.required'=>'error message',
    'first_name.alpha'=>'error message',
    'first_name.max'=>'error message',
    'last_name.required'=>'error message',
    'last_name.alpha'=>'error message',
    'last_name.max'=>'error message',
    'email.required'=>'error message',
    'email.email'=>'error message',
    'email.unique'=>'error message',
    'username.required'=>'error message',
    'username.max'=>'error message',
    'username.unique'=>'error message',
);
$this->validate($req,$rules,$messages);
```

Comment: How are you setting the validation errors?

Comment: That 500 is probably an exception, check your logs

Comment: @Wader i am using laravel defaults

Comment: @543310 Can you post your validation/controller code? Theres many ways to get error messages into the session.

Comment: @RDelorier this is my log file : https://www.mediafire.com/?f1pprctx6uxyzd5

Comment: @Wader i added my validation code

Comment: Use `$errors->isEmpty()` to check if you have errors or not.

Comment: @Marwelln already have error. but when i refresh the page this error still remains...

Comment: Are you by any chance modifying the validator messages and returning them to the view as $error in a different format?

Comment: @RDelorier no i just use laravel defaults that documented on laravel's website

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: `\Session::flush('errors');`

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $('#workerAppModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
      <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
      </ul>
  </div>
  @php
    \Session::flush('errors');
  @endphp
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i created sample and it's working fine with refresh it clears the messages :-

```
Route::get('/formTest',function (){
    return view('testForm');
});

Route::post('/formSubmit',function (Request $request){
    if($request->get('uuids') === null){
        $message = [
            'required' => 'Name is required',
            'number'   => 'And It should be number'
        ];
    }else{
        dd($request->get('get'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['uuids' => $message]);    
})->name('submitForm');
```

[image]